# I have multi lines in my code, I want to write certain lines in a new line, how can I do it in groovy body

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

```
body:"""
Hi, how are you? Yes, I am doing good. what about you. How are things going?
Nothing interesting, as usual.
"""
```

In the above lines, I want to print a sentence in new line in groovy (body), how can I accomplish that?
Note: I am new to groovy

I tried using b tag and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done it correctly...

```
body:"""Hi, how are you?
Yes, I am doing good.
what about you.
How are things going?
Nothing interesting, as usual."""
```

You can also ask the system for the correct line separator, since it can change on different operating systems.

```
writer << "Line 1" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Line 2"
```

Comment: I tried something and it worked, now I am trying to include HTML tags. My requirement is to add something like, thanks and regards (in one line), in next line a image, followed by name (in new line), kindly let me know how I can achieve this

Comment: First you need to select this answer as correct and you can upvote it if you want to.
Then you need to create a new question for the next issue you have.